# vba print out an three dimension data

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, printing

how to display a 3-dimension array without knowing its exactsize? If the variable name is DataSet. But I'm not sure the height and the length.       In Macro,

```
msgbox(DataSet) 'type mismatch
msgbox(DataSet(0,0,0))'subscript out of range
```

or give general example. Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: How do you want it to display?  3-dimensional arrays are hard to display on a 2-dimensional screen without explicitly telling it how to display

Answer (score 1):

You can always nest a `For` loop as such:

```
For d1 = 0 to Ubound(myArray,1)
    For d2 = 0 to UBound(myArray,2)
        For d3 = 0 to UBound(myArray, 3)
            sValue = sValue & vbNewLine & myArray(d1, d2, d3)
        Next
    Next
Next
MsgBox sValue
```

Comment: I would like to replace `0` to `Lbound(myArray,1)`, `Lbound(myArray,2)`, `Lbound(myArray,3)` .